# Method returning the same pointer address?

Tags: c++, pointers

I realize this may be a too localized question, but I am new to pointers, and this may help others if I am doing something wrong.

For a project, we are creating an `OrdListClass`, derived from a `ListClass` object that my professor has created. `ListClass` is an object file, so I do not have the source for it.

So far, I've been doing ver well with the project, however I hit this snag when dealing with `Operator==`.

I use `myList == yourList` to call the operator.

My logic is to use the method he has provided in `ListClass` called `GetListPtr()` for both the current applying object, and the object we are comparing it to, `rtOp`.

However, when using

```
ItemType* currPosPtr = GetListPtr(); //this class' List Pointer
```

and

```
ItemType* rtOpPosPtr = rtOp.GetListPtr(); //rtOp object's list pointer
```

They return the same pointer address?

I am not sure if this a fault of mine, or possibly an error in the object file I have been given.

```
    bool OrdListClass::operator== (const OrdListClass& rtOp) const  
{
    ItemType* currPosPtr = GetListPtr(); //this class' List Pointer
    ItemType* rtOpPosPtr = rtOp.GetListPtr(); //rtOp object's list pointer

    if (GetLength() == rtOp.GetLength()){ //If the lengths are equal
        /*** DO KEY COMPARISONS HERE ***/
    }else{ //Lengths are unequal
        return false; //List can't contain the same items
    }//End lengths if

    return true; //All items were compared, all keys match
}//End Operator ==
```

[image: Pointer addresses - as viewed in the watch window in Visual Studio 2010]

Comment: Can we see the code which creates the two objects and checks for equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible explanation is that `*this` and `rtOp` are the same object.

Another is that they are two distinct objects, but share the same list pointer (you seem to be implying that this shouldn't be the case, but are not saying why).

Comment: Previously in my test client, I used `yourList = myList`. In my `Operator=` method, I accidentally gave `yourList` `myList`'s list pointer. Thanks for pointing this out (no pun intended).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that the implementation you haven't the source code, it has an static list, so it's the same for all the instances. This may be the reason you are getting the same address for two different objects